# How to get what ATA Standards are supported by HDD?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, hardware, hard-drive

How to get ATA Standards that are supported by HDD? I'm using C++, WINAPI. I can't use WMI.

I meen these ATA Standards: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2028834&seqNum=2

I'm already using this struct in my project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559006(v=vs.85).aspx , but there no information about supported ATA standards.

I'm looking for any programm solution, I think that if need I can write to a file supported standards with other language and then read them with c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `0xEC` ATA command to HDD and retrieve `IDENTIFY_DEVICE_DATA` structure, which contain information about your HDD.
It requires `irb.h` library include from WDK (Windows Driver Kit).

```
BOOL getAtaCompliance() { 
  DWORD dwBytes;
  BOOL  bResult;

  CONST UINT bufferSize = 512;
  CONST BYTE identifyDataCommandId =  0xEC;

  UCHAR identifyDataBuffer[bufferSize
        + sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX)] = { 0 };

  ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX & PTE = *(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX *) identifyDataBuffer;
  PTE.Length = sizeof(PTE);
  PTE.TimeOutValue = 10;
  PTE.DataTransferLength = 512;
  PTE.DataBufferOffset = sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX);

  IDEREGS * ideRegs = (IDEREGS *) PTE.CurrentTaskFile;
  ideRegs->bCommandReg = identifyDataCommandId;
  ideRegs->bSectorCountReg = 1;

  PTE.AtaFlags = ATA_FLAGS_DATA_IN | ATA_FLAGS_DRDY_REQUIRED;

  bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH, &PTE,
                      sizeof(identifyDataBuffer), &PTE,
                      sizeof(identifyDataBuffer), &dwBytes, 0);

  if (bResult == FALSE) {
    std::cout << "Oops, something went wrong, error code: "
              << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return bResult;
  }

  WORD *data = (WORD *)(identifyDataBuffer + sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX));

  int16_t ataSupportBits = data[80];

  return bResult;
}
```

ataSupportBits will contain 16 bits about supported ATA standarts. 
From [Information technology - AT Attachment 8 - ATA/ATAPI Command Set (ATA8-ACS)](http://www.t13.org/documents/uploadeddocuments/docs2007/d1699r4a-ata8-acs.pdf)

[image: word #80, ATA/ATAPI Compliance bitmap]